# Can we find page count of a file in Unix/Linux?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I want to count number of pages in the file `/var/log/messages`, so that I can use `pr` command to start printing from the page I want to.

For example, suppose that `/var/log/messages` file contains 300 pages, then I can use the following to print last 5 pages.

```
pr +295 /var/log/messages
```

Note: `pr` command will list the page count when we specify page number that exceeds number of pages available in the file as mentioned below.

```
pr +400 /var/log/messages
pr: starting page number 400 exceeds page count 313
```

Having said that I would like know if there is a specific command to find the page count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pr` default page length for text file is `56`. So you can do like this:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX=ceil -nle 'END{print ceil($./56)}' file
```

If you want to count many files, try:

```
$ perl -MPOSIX=ceil -nle '
    if (eof) {
        print ceil($./56);
        close ARGV;
    }
' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Note that if some lines are wider than the default column width (72 characters), this method won't work.

Comment: @Igeorget: I think page width is not applied to this case.  Can you give an example?

Comment: Indeed, my bad, at second sight, it's not applied, which is strange for a printing formatting tool. But there is nonetheless a difference between your results and the output of `pr` because you don't take into account the header and footer. I suggest `$./66` instead of `$./56` if footers and headers are desired in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I built quite a horrible hack to extract this information from `pr` output itself. If you use `pr` on a file, by default, it will output on each page a header with the page number of the form

```
2014-07-04 11:40                   file.txt                    Page 1
```

So, you can run `pr` on the file, extract the last header from the output, and from that header, extract the page number.

For instance, with one of the following commands:

```
pr file.txt | awk '/file.txt\s+Page/{ print $5; }' | tail -n1
```

or

```
pr file.txt | awk '/file.txt/ && /Page/{ print $5; }' | tail -n1
```

You get the desired information.

Example:

```
> pr grapher.cpp | awk '/file.txt .* Page/'
2014-07-04 11:40                   file.txt                    Page 1
2014-07-04 11:40                   file.txt                    Page 2

> pr file.txt | awk '/file.txt\s+Page/{ print $5; }' | tail -n1
2
```

One of the advantage of this method is that you can tweak the number of lines and columns through `pr` options and still get the correct result. The only problem is that some options remove the header from the output...

Comment: @Igeorget This command "pr /var/log/messages | awk '/messages.txt\s+Page/{ print $5; }' | tail -n1" does not give output..No error reported...

Comment: @Igeorget What is the function of "s+page" in the above command,it does not seems to be working on my machine.

Comment: @AkheelAsadi Hmm, it may depend on your version of awk then. It's supposed to match any sequence of blank characters (space, tabs, etc.). I'll figure it out.

Comment: @AkheelAsadi You can use another syntax which should work on more awk versions. `/message.txt/ && /Page/{print $5;}`.